# Dependencies issue while installing Graphviz 2.28

Tags: monitoring, rhel6, nagios, centreon

I want to install this packages for Nagvis :

```
graphviz-2.28.0-1.el6.i686.rpm
graphviz-doc-2.28.0-1.el6.i686.rpm
graphviz-gd-2.28.0-1.el6.i686.rpm
graphviz-graphs-2.28.0-1.el6.i686.rpm
graphviz-perl-2.28.0-1.el6.i686.rpm
```

But while installing, i have this error :

```
# rpm -ivh graphviz-2.28.0-1.el6.i686.rpm 

erreur: Dépendances requises:
        libgdkglext-x11-1.0.so.0 est nécessaire pour graphviz-2.28.0-1.el6.i686
        libglut.so.3 est nécessaire pour graphviz-2.28.0-1.el6.i686
        libgtkglext-x11-1.0.so.0 est nécessaire pour graphviz-2.28.0-1.el6.i686
        libgts-0.7.so.5 est nécessaire pour graphviz-2.28.0-1.el6.i686
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you configured yum server on your server it will resolve all dependencies from repositories. After configuring yum you should run the following command.
**yum install Nagvis**
if yum install this without any problem or any dependencies requirement than it's ok 
if yum also show some dependencies then you have to install them manually them and after completing dependencies you should run again yum install Nagvis.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Installing these RPMs fixed the problem : http://pastebin.com/1GyfuE5A